# F test fails but t-test does not?

Tags: f-test

I'm a bit confused about this.
I have a model with multiple variables trying to explain the dependent variable.
When I use the F test, I don't pass the critical value.
But when I seperate the different variables and use the t-test, I do pass the critical value on 2 of the 3 variables.
How is this possible?
I thought the F test was to be used as a indicator: is any of the variables relevant. 
And I thought the t-test was to determine which one was relevant.

Comment: what is the model and what are the variables